# Excel: Highlight row and column by given numbers

Tags: excel, row, highlight

I have a chart I am trying to automate in excel. There are two input values, one is in the first column and the second is in the row containing the first input. For example I would have the inputs 3 and 50. So the row starting with 3 would be highlighted and then the column containing 50 in that row would be highlighted. This would make it easy to see that result b is the correct outcome.

[image: Example Chart]
.

I have the row highlighting figured out with a simple conditional format. Using something like =$A4=$F$1 where F1 is the input value.

The column highlighting is more difficult as it has to be based off finding a value inside of a row that is determined by another value. This is what I could use some help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**
Select Cell A18

Use formula to determine CF,

And use `=OR($A18=$A$33,INDEX(A$18:A$31,MATCH($A$33,$A$18:$A$31,0),0)=$B$33)`

Then apply the formula to your range

If your table goes bast 6 rows, change A$6 in the count if part, to the bottom row of the table.

Comment: I mostly understand the theory of this and got the example it was based on working. I then tried scaling it up to my actual chart and the row is highlighting but the column is not. The column only seems to work when the top two rows are highlighted. My test file is linked below. Thanks
http://www.filedropper.com/highlighttest

Comment: I'll have a blast at it in the morning when I get to work dude !

Comment: Use Formula =OR($A18=$A$33,INDEX(A$18:A$31,MATCH($A$33,$A$18:$A$31,0),0)=$B$33) in CELL A18 of your sheet, then apply to whole table.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional formatting formula is:

```
 =OR(ROW(A1) = MATCH($F$1,$A:$A,0),COLUMN(A1) = MATCH($F$2,INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH($F$1,$A:$A,0),0),0))
```

[image]